# Is there research into associative/commutative optimizations?

Tags: compilers, program-optimization

While playing around with optimization sets in LLVM, it occurs to me that the order in which optimizations are run matters greatly since, in general, `A(B(src))` is not equal to `B(A(src))` where `A` and `B` are some optimization of type `source -> source` and `src` is of type `source`.

Are there optimizations for which that property holds? Are there projects or research that attempt to formalize or otherwise create these types of optimizations?

Comment: I'm not sure what kind of answer you are expecting.  A list of all pairs of optimizations that commute would be too broad for this site.

Comment: What information is available? Are there optimizations that commute? I'm not asking for an exhaustive list.

Comment: @oconnor0 What do you mean by optimisations don't commute. In general, optimisations should preserve the semantics of the original program, so $A \circ B$ should have the same meaning as $B \circ A$. To be sure, $A \circ B$ often does not result in the same code as $B \circ A$. So there are different notions of "the same" at play, which one are you interested in?

Comment: I'm interested in the same code, not the same semantics. At a crude level, I am interested in commuting optimizations such that `diff` "$A \circ B$" "$B \circ A$" returns no differences.